# API Rest - OneToMany / ManyTone with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

I have the following relationship with this two entities

· Sport has Many SportTranslation

· SportTranslation belongsTo Sport

· Is Bidirectional

When I try to access from SportTranslation to Sport I recieve the following error.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:454) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:510) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

The error is not clear and the tables are not empty.

· I have the classical following Spring MVC architecture

The controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/public/sports")
public class SportController implements ISportsController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SportController.class);


    @Autowired
    private SportsMethods sportMethods;

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<List<SportDTO>> getSports(Pageable pageable) {
        logger.info("--- Retrieve name of class --- : " +this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " --- Method name --- : " + new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName());

        List<SportDTO> sportsMethodsList = sportMethods.retreiveListSports(pageable);

        logger.info("--- Final list ---" + sportsMethodsList);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<SportDTO>>(sportsMethodsList,
                (sportsMethodsList == null || sportsMethodsList.isEmpty()) ? HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT : HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

· Class Methods

@Component
public class SportsMethods {

```
@Autowired
private SportService sportService;

public List<SportDTO> retreiveListSports(Pageable pageable) {

    List<SportDTO> sportList = sportService.retreiveListSports();

    return sportList;
}
```

}

· The service

```
@Component
public class SportService implements ISportService {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SportService.class);

    @Autowired
    private SportRepository sportRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SportAdapter sportAdapter;

    @Override
    public List<SportDTO> retreiveListSports() {

        List<Sport> sportList = sportRepository.findAll();

        logger.info("--- Retrieve List Of Sports---"+sportList);

        List<SportDTO > sportListDTO = sportAdapter.convertListSport2ListSportDTO(sportList);

        logger.info("--- Retrieve a List Of SportsDTO" +sportListDTO);

        return sportListDTO;

    }

}
```

· The two adapters (SportAdatper , SportTranslationAdapter)

· SportAdapter

@Component
public class SportAdapter {

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SportAdapter.class);

@Autowired
private SportTranslationAdapter sportTranslationAdapter;

public List<SportDTO> convertListSport2ListSportDTO(List<Sport> sportList) {

    logger.info("--- Sport List adapter" + sportList);

    List<SportDTO> sportDTOList = new ArrayList<SportDTO>();

    for (Sport sport : sportList) {

        SportDTO sportDTO = new SportDTO();
        sportDTO.setId(sport.getId());
        sportDTO.setClave(sport.getClave());
        sportDTO.setSportTranslationDTO(sportTranslationAdapter.convertSportTranslation2SportTranslationDTO(sport.getSportTranslation()));
        sportDTOList.add(sportDTO);
    }


    logger.info("--- Sport DTO List adapter" + sportDTOList);

    return sportDTOList;
}
```

· SportTranslationAdapter

```
@Component
public class SportTranslationAdapter {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SportTranslationAdapter.class);

    public List<SportTranslationDTO> convertSportTranslation2SportTranslationDTO(List<SportTranslation> list) {
        List<SportTranslationDTO> sportTranslationDTOList = new ArrayList<SportTranslationDTO>();
        for (SportTranslation sportTranslation : list) {
            SportTranslationDTO sportTranslationDTO = new SportTranslationDTO();            
                        sportTranslationDTO.setSportId(sportTranslation.getSport().getId());
            sportTranslationDTO.setName(sportTranslation.getName());
            sportTranslationDTOList.add(sportTranslationDTO);

        }
        return sportTranslationDTOList;
    }

}
```

· Entities Sport and SportTranslation

· Sport

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sport")
public class Sport implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "sport_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "clave")
    private String clave;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sport_id")
    private List<SportTranslation> sportTranslation;
```

·SportTranslation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sportstranslation")
public class SportTranslation implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "sportstranslation_id")
    private long idSportTranslation;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "sport_id", nullable = true)
    private Sport sport;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "language_id", nullable = true)
    private Language languageId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

· Language is working correctly ,but this is not the problem the problem is with Sport.

Could anyone helps to me?

Comment: Show us Entity classes code.

Comment: @AdityaNarayanDixit sorry I forgotten

Comment: Yea, you have a StackOverflowError error because you have a cyclic dependency. It would be better to use a 'mappedBy' for `private List<SportTranslation> sportTranslation;` instead of a `JoinColumn`. You should definitely show the SQL and examine it carefully. You seem to have too many columns named sport_id in your schema, that will be confusing. You have dumped too much code here, you need to do some debugging on your own first and narrow down the issues you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest your entity association to updated as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sport")
public class Sport implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "sport_id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "clave")
private String clave;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "sport", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<SportTranslation> sportTranslation;

@Entity
@Table(name = "sportstranslation")
public class SportTranslation implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "sportstranslation_id")
private long idSportTranslation;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "sport_id", nullable = true)
private Sport sport;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "language_id", nullable = true)
private Language languageId;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
```

Also, annotate your service method in which you are fetching data with `@Transactional`.

Comment: In my entity sport I cant' use the attributes with  annotation @JoinColumn  ,probably could be with my jpa version?

Comment: It works but I made this different ,     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sport", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)